# How min_activated_stake and total_activated_stake is calculated?

Tags: smart-contract, block-producer, voting

I have a query, in the `producer_pay` contract, i don't understand how `min_activated_stake` is calculated [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/release/1.6.x/contracts/eosio.system/src/producer_pay.cpp#L8).

Also how total_activated_stake is calculated,
I've seen that default it's value is defined 0 [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/release/1.6.x/contracts/eosio.system/include/eosio.system/eosio.system.hpp#L92).

But there are many other definitions of `total_activated_stake` are defined in `delegate_bandwidth` and voting smart contract.

Can you please explain me using some example.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of `min_activated_stake` is hard-coded to have 15% of total amount of token. [[link]](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/897d88c68599db3cdbf8d60412c397f429455d84/contracts/eosio.system/include/eosio.system/eosio.system.hpp#L66)

On EOS mainnet, the initial amount of token is 1B, so min_activated_stake is set to 150M.

`total_activated_stake` is counted every time when each user does his first vote. [[link]](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/897d88c68599db3cdbf8d60412c397f429455d84/contracts/eosio.system/src/voting.cpp#L190-L200) When its value exceeds min_activated_stake, block rewards start working.